# Overlay filter in LibAV/FFMpeg returns strange (tripled) frame in C

Tags: c, image-processing, ffmpeg, libav

I tried to make a program, which merges two frames. I use LibAV (libav-win32-20140428) under Windows 7 64 and Visual Studio 2013.
But the result is quite odd.

[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/rcobnm.jpg]

The filter which was used is Overlay. When I change the graph, to the one, that uses only one stream and add FADE effect, everything works like a charm. But OVERLAY and eg. DRAWBOX give me strange distortion (three frames on one and black and white effect). Here is the code:

```
static int init_filter_graph(AVFilterGraph **pGraph, AVFilterContext **pSrc1, AVFilterContext **pSink)
{
    AVFilterGraph* tFilterGraph;
    AVFilterContext* tBufferContext1;
    AVFilter* tBuffer1;
    AVFilterContext* tColorContext;
    AVFilter* tColor;
    AVFilterContext* tOverlayContext;
    AVFilter* tOverlay;
    AVFilterContext* tBufferSinkContext;
    AVFilter* tBufferSink;

    int tError;

    /* Create a new filtergraph, which will contain all the filters. */
    tFilterGraph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    if (!tFilterGraph) {
        return -1;
    }

    { // BUFFER FILTER 1
        tBuffer1 = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        if (!tBuffer1) {
            return -1;
        }
        tBufferContext1 = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(tFilterGraph, tBuffer1, "src1");
        if (!tBufferContext1) {
            return -1;
        }

        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "width", "320", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "height", "240", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "pix_fmt", "bgr24", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "time_base", "1/25", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "sar", "1", 0);
        tError = avfilter_init_dict(tBufferContext1, &tOptionsDict);
        av_dict_free(&tOptionsDict);
        if (tError < 0) {
            return tError;
        }
    }

    { // COLOR FILTER
        tColor = avfilter_get_by_name("color");
        if (!tColor) {
            return -1;
        }
        tColorContext = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(tFilterGraph, tColor, "color");
        if (!tColorContext) {
            return -1;
        }

        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "color", "white", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "size", "20x120", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "framerate", "1/25", 0);
        tError = avfilter_init_dict(tColorContext, &tOptionsDict);
        av_dict_free(&tOptionsDict);
        if (tError < 0) {
            return tError;
        }
    }

    { // OVERLAY FILTER
        tOverlay = avfilter_get_by_name("overlay");
        if (!tOverlay) {
            return -1;
        }
        tOverlayContext = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(tFilterGraph, tOverlay, "overlay");
        if (!tOverlayContext) {
            return -1;
        }

        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "x", "0", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "y", "0", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "main_w", "120", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "main_h", "140", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "overlay_w", "320", 0);
        av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "overlay_h", "240", 0);
        tError = avfilter_init_dict(tOverlayContext, &tOptionsDict);
        av_dict_free(&tOptionsDict);
        if (tError < 0) {
            return tError;
        }
    }

    { // BUFFERSINK FILTER
        tBufferSink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!tBufferSink) {
            return -1;
        }

        tBufferSinkContext = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(tFilterGraph, tBufferSink, "sink");
        if (!tBufferSinkContext) {
            return -1;
        }

        tError = avfilter_init_str(tBufferSinkContext, NULL);
        if (tError < 0) {
            return tError;
        }
    }

    // Linking graph
    tError = avfilter_link(tBufferContext1, 0, tOverlayContext, 0);
    if (tError >= 0) {
        tError = avfilter_link(tColorContext, 0, tOverlayContext, 1);
    }
    if (tError >= 0) {
        tError = avfilter_link(tOverlayContext, 0, tBufferSinkContext, 0);
    }
    if (tError < 0) {
        return tError;
    }

    tError = avfilter_graph_config(tFilterGraph, NULL);
    if (tError < 0) {
        return tError;
    }

    *pGraph = tFilterGraph;
    *pSrc1 = tBufferContext1;
    *pSink = tBufferSinkContext;

    return 0;
}
```

What do you think is the reason?

Comment: Did you try FFmpeg too, or are you just adding its tag?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hi, Lord. I also tried the FFMpeg and the effect is even worst. There is not even that white rectangle on the top of the frame(s). Here is the whole file (it compiles under FFMpeg and LibAV. http://pastebin.com/QQJqWp6Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a hint from Luca Barbato at [LibAV's mailing list](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-api/2014-July/000890.html):

> Can you try to reproduce that with avconv? From the image looks like you
>   are getting a pixel format you are not really expecting.
>
> lu

And I discovered, that I need to use [Format Filter](https://libav.org/libavfilter.html#format), to keep the pixels' format the same.
So I added:

```
{ // FORMAT FILTER
    tFormat = avfilter_get_by_name("format");
    if (!tFormat) {
        // Could not find the tFormat filter.
        return -1;
    }

    tFormatContext = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(tFilterGraph, tFormat, "format");
    if (!tFormatContext) {
        // Could not allocate the tFormat instance.
        return -1;
    }

    av_dict_set(&tOptionsDict, "pix_fmts", "bgr24", 0);
    tError = avfilter_init_dict(tFormatContext, &tOptionsDict);
    av_dict_free(&tOptionsDict);
    if (tError < 0) {
        // Could not initialize the tFormat filter.
        return tError;
    }
}
```

in **init_filter_graph** function.

And now my filter graph looks like this:

```
tError = avfilter_link(tBufferContext1, 0, tOverlayContext, 0);
if (tError >= 0)
{
    tError = avfilter_link(tColorContext, 0, tOverlayContext, 1);
}
if (tError >= 0)
{
    tError = avfilter_link(tOverlayContext, 0, tFormatContext, 0);
}
if (tError >= 0)
{
    tError = avfilter_link(tFormatContext, 0, tBufferSinkContext, 0);
}
if (tError < 0) { // Error connecting filters.
    return tError;
}
```

The distortion is gone and color is back!

[image]